# Maximum length of command line arguments passed to Delphi console application

Tags: delphi, command-line-arguments

Is there a maximum limit how long strings can be passed to Delphi console application? I am thinking of passing in a lots of JSON data. I would read the data in with ParamStr(x) function.

Comment: For more information check this link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830473/en-us

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The commandline is [limited](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830473) by the OS to 2047 characters.

If you want to use more data, you can use a file.

Comment: On Windows XP or later, the maximum length is 8191 characters. On Windows 2000 or NT4, the maximum length is 2047 characters. According to the link you provided.

Comment: This answer is not correct, according to Raymond Chen (see my answer). Not downvoting, just mentioning.

Answer (score 12):

The max length for CMD.EXE is 8192 characters. This would be the max amount receivable by a Delphi console app because of a limitation in CMD.EXE itself.

The max command length for CreateProcess is 32767 characters. This is due to the UNICODE_STRING structure.

ShellExecute/EX is limited to the INTERNET_MAX_URL_LENGTH, which as Gamecat mentioned is 2047 characters, unless you're running on Win95; there the limit is only MAX_PATH.

For more info, see [Raymond Chen's blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/12/10/56028.aspx)

Comment: +1 I think OP accepted the wrong answer! Console apps don't need to be started from cmd.exe.

Answer (score 1):

For 'lots of data', using ParamStr could be too limited. Have you considered to use an [(anonymous) pipe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365139%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)? Here is a starting point:

[Start two processes and connect them with a pipe in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957490/start-two-processes-and-connect-them-with-a-pipe-in-delphi)