# Maximum path constant for an UNC path on Windows?

Tags: winapi, path, filesystems, constants

I know that for regular path I can use the `MAX_PATH` constant to create a string long enough to hold a path. However, how about UNC paths?

[According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), I understand they can be up to 32,767 characters, so is there a constant defined for that? If not, is there any other way to create a string long enough for such paths? I know I can just hard-code it, but would like to avoid this, if possible.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5194824/62576) to another question might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this exists. If you look on the same page [but a bit further down](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#maxpath), you can see:

> **Note**  The maximum path of 32,767 characters is approximate, because the "\?\" prefix may be expanded to a longer string by the
>   system at run time, and this expansion applies to the total length.

Comment: Yes I read this part too, I was thinking maybe there's some smart Winapi function that would dynamically give me the correct length for a given path.

Answer (score 3):

The constant `UNICODE_STRING_MAX_CHARS` is defined as 32767 in winnt.h.